# create a nested array recursively in angular-10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Following is my array - Name (categoriesData)

```
[{"categoryCode":"cat1","name":"Procurement","parentCategoryCode":"ROOT_NODE","active":true,"archive":false,"children":[]}]
```

There is a object and it looks like - Name (categoryData)

```
{"8596":{"operation":true,"children":[]},"9890":{"operation":true,"children":[{"categoryCode":"8596","name":"Sub-Sub-Sub-Procurement","parentCategoryCode":"9890","active":true,"archive":false}]},"125240":{"operation":true,"children":[{"categoryCode":"9890","name":"Syb-Sub-Procurement","parentCategoryCode":"125240","active":true,"archive":false}]},"dvs":{"operation":true,"children":[]},"cat1":{"operation":true,"children":[{"categoryCode":"125240","name":"Procurement-Sub","parentCategoryCode":"cat1","active":true,"archive":false}]}}
```

In categoriesData, the object has children and is empty.

But this will be recursive, the categoryCode is cat1 and cat1 has children in categoryData and in that children of cat1 in categoryData has categoryCode 125240 and 125240 has children in categoryData and this will go on till the time the categoryData children for that specific category code is empty.

Can any one help?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your categoriesData array data  as (this.categoryCode and final = {}):

```
[{"categoryCode":"cat1","name":"Procurement","parentCategoryCode":"ROOT_NODE","active":true,"archive":false,"children":[]}]
```

your categoryData as (this.value1) :

```
{"8596":{"operation":true,"children":[]},"9890":{"operation":true,"children":[{"categoryCode":"8596","name":"Sub-Sub-Sub-Procurement","parentCategoryCode":"9890","active":true,"archive":false}]},"125240":{"operation":true,"children":[{"categoryCode":"9890","name":"Syb-Sub-Procurement","parentCategoryCode":"125240","active":true,"archive":false}]},"dvs":{"operation":true,"children":[]},"cat1":{"operation":true,"children":[{"categoryCode":"125240","name":"Procurement-Sub","parentCategoryCode":"cat1","active":true,"archive":false}]}}
```

Typescript code

```
  utils(){
for(let  i= 0 ; i< this.categoriesData.length; i++){
  this.help(this.categoriesData[i]['categoryCode']);
  this.categoriesData[i]['children'] = this.final['children'];
}
console.log(this.categoriesData)
```

}

```
help(code) {

if (!this.categoryData[code].children.length) {
  this.final = this.categoryData[code]['children'];
  return this.categoryData[code];
}
this.help(this.categoryData[code]['children'][0]['categoryCode']);
this.final = { ['children']: [{ ...this.categoryData[code]['children'][0], ...this.final }] }
```

}

your final output

```
[
{
    "categoryCode": "cat1",
    "name": "Procurement",
    "parentCategoryCode": "ROOT_NODE",
    "active": true,
    "archive": false,
    "children": [
        {
            "categoryCode": "125240",
            "name": "Procurement-Sub",
            "parentCategoryCode": "cat1",
            "active": true,
            "archive": false,
            "children": [
                {
                    "categoryCode": "9890",
                    "name": "Syb-Sub-Procurement",
                    "parentCategoryCode": "125240",
                    "active": true,
                    "archive": false,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "categoryCode": "8596",
                            "name": "Sub-Sub-Sub-Procurement",
                            "parentCategoryCode": "9890",
                            "active": true,
                            "archive": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

]